# Getting missing Datetime intervals using sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I have a question, currently I am having simple table:

```
timestamp(DATETIME) | cardId(INT)|channelId(INT)|
--------------------|------------|--------------|
2018-01-16 11:00:08 |      1     |      2       |
2018-01-16 11:00:13 |      1     |      2       |
2018-01-16 11:00:14 |      1     |      2       |
2018-01-16 11:00:17 |      1     |      2       |
2018-01-16 11:00:08 |      1     |      1       |
2018-01-16 11:00:13 |      1     |      1       |
2018-01-16 11:00:14 |      1     |      1       |
2018-01-16 11:00:17 |      1     |      1       |
```

Now i want to create a query that will find me a missing seconds in that date time(where first timestamp for combination card id and channel id is minimum timestamp for that group, same goes for max. in this case for 1-2 card channel group min would be 2018-01-16 11:00:08 and max 2018-01-16 11:00:17. So i need missing seconds for each group in that defined time interval) and group it by card id and source id, result should be something like something like:

```
missing(DATETIME) | cardId(INT)|channelId(INT)|
--------------------|------------|--------------|
2018-01-16 11:00:09 |      1     |      2       |
2018-01-16 11:00:10 |      1     |      2       |
2018-01-16 11:00:11 |      1     |      2       |
2018-01-16 11:00:12 |      1     |      2       |
2018-01-16 11:00:09 |      1     |      1       |
2018-01-16 11:00:10 |      1     |      1       |
2018-01-16 11:00:11 |      1     |      1       |
2018-01-16 11:00:12 |      1     |      1       |
```

etc.

So far i came up with an idea of using recursive as template for time intervals like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(timestamp) AS (
select min(timestamp)from data
    UNION ALL
SELECT datetime(timestamp, '+1 second')
FROM cte
WHERE timestamp < (select max(timestamp) from data))
```

This will give me all seconds in min and max of data table, now I am looking for a way top get info I need, tried with:

```
select CardId, ChannelId, data.timestamp as existingTimestamp, cte.timestamp as missingTimestamp
from data left outer join cte using (timestamp) order by CardId, ChannelId;
```

But it only joins existing values, is there a way or m,ayby more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, you may create a group of all expected `timestamps`, `cardId` and `channelId` and exclude those that happen:

```
SELECT cte.timestamp, data.cardId, data.channelID FROM cte JOIN data 
EXCEPT SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY cardId, channelId, timestamp;
```

Also, you must correct your CTE, to `... WHERE timestamp <= (SELECT MAX(...`, because one of the cards/channels may fail also this last second!